# What influence the sorting of a query on Elastic Search?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

The way mapping / analyzer is defined, influence a sorting of a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, they are sorted by score, which is calculated (again, by default) using a tf-idf algorithm, documented in Lucene's [TFIDFSimilarity documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).  You can specify sorting criteria yourself, see [ElasticSearch's Sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html).